Copy and emulate locker tag
We have a new system in our school to open our lockers, you have to scan your school card. Now I dont wanna always cary my card close to me, i cant put it behind my phone, because those arent allowed and need to be inside the locker or at home. I wanna emulate the card with my watch if thats possible. I found this video: https://youtu.be/0gZSjsZOE1M?si=SW4MTRAKUauph0sq showcasing the flipper zero, but I dont wanna purchase a €100+ device just for this. Anyone know if this is possible? I know coding but know nothing about nfc.
When i read the tag with nfc tools it shows this.

Not possible with a standard watch or phone.
Mifare Classic Tags are a propitiatory format and it does not conform to any NFC standard type.
Most hardware manufacturer make their hardware capable of emulating the most common NFC type being NFC Type 4A as this is not a propitiatory format of one many hardware manufacturers.
While the hardware is capable on an i Device, Apple only allow themselves and a few selected partners to operate at this level of emulating NFC Type 4A Tags.
On Android phones any developer can emulate a NFC Type 4A.
On all watches I believe this kind of functionality is also restricted to the manufacturer.

Do you know any cheap devices that I can use?
